# How the stoppage of a systemd service can trigger the stoppage of different one?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, startupscript

I'm creating a  systemd service let's call it B on Ubuntu 16.04 which I'd like on every boot to start after a specific service called A and then run a specific script. So far I've created the service unit file which consists of the following fields:

```
[Unit]
Description=B
After=A.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/B.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Furthermore I'd like the stoppage of service A to trigger the stoppage of service B. Is it valid to do it with the following command in the A service unit file

```
ExecStop=systemctl stop A.service
```

or is there another way ? If possible I'd like not to change the existing A service file unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two `systemd` features to solve your problem.

First, you can use a `drop-in` file to extend an existing `systemd` conf file without modifying it. Here's the pattern:

1. Create `/etc/systemd/system/A.d/stop-b.conf`.
2. Add this to it:

`[Service]
    ExecStopPost=systemctl stop B.service`

That would be if you wanted to stop B when A is stopped. The second feature you see in use is the `ExecStopPost=` directive, to cause run an additional command when a service is stopped.